# How to styling div with CSS fixed width and auto-resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create **container** div that has width between 800px to 1000px.

Inside, it has two div and want to fix left div to 250px.

For the right div I want it make width-resize automatically

[jsfiddle examle](http://jsfiddle.net/marco83/vn84nm30/4/)

HTML

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            Left div<br />(fixed to 250px)
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            Right div<br />(width fit to blue area left)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%; 
    min-width: 800px; 
    max-width: 1100px; 
    background-color: #06F; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 420px; 
    padding: 10px 0px;    
}
.left {
    width: 250px; 
    float: left; 
    height: 200px; 
    background-color: #0F0;
}
.right {
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #F00; 
    height: 200px; 
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it. It uses `calc` (http://jsfiddle.net/vn84nm30/6/)

```
.right {
    width: calc(100% - 250px); 
    background-color: #F00; 
    height: 200px; 
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Yes, those people use XP or Vista, they cry by default.

Comment: Hahahah yes ;D How about mobile?  ... maybe its early to use clac. Not really necessary in this case. Is calc faster that normal css?

Comment: It's supported by all modern mobile browsers. It's working on my Windows Phone 8.1. I don't know if it's faster, I find it more logical and it requires far lesser logic to work.

Comment: Try to remove float: left on the red div ;) Its less logic maybe but its simplier. And you will save a bit of bits :D

Comment: This problem has many solutions, however width is easily done. Height is problematic. `calc` really comes to its right when you need to make an element have 100%, but there's a header or a footer that also takes up space. If you know they have a fixed height, `calc` is your friend.

Comment: Responsive is taking over :D The things going to change. But you are clearly free to use whatever you need!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add `display: flex` to the parent, `.container` element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vbey5mv5/)

```
.container {
    width: 100%; 
    min-width: 800px; 
    max-width: 1100px; 
    background-color: #06F; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 420px; 
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: flex;
}
```

Alternatively, you could set the `display` of the parent, `.container` element to `table`, and then set the children elements to `display: table-cell`. If you want the children elements to respect the width, set `table-layout: fixed` on the parent element:

[**Alternative Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mhkfjjhj/)

```
.container {
    width: 100%; 
    min-width: 800px; 
    max-width: 1100px; 
    background-color: #06F; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 420px; 
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.left {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px; 
    background-color: #0F0;
    display: table-cell;
}
.right {
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #F00; 
    height: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Flex boxes are nice. Didn't we met each other on this a few days ago?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove float:right on the red div :D or
Maybe like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vn84nm30/8/

Used table features ;)

top div :     `display: table;`

container : `display: table-row`

removed float left
the height is decided by parent :D

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```css
.container {
    width: 100%; 
    min-width: 800px; 
    max-width: 1100px; 
    background-color: #06F; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 420px; 
    padding: 10px 0px;
    
    
}
.left {
    width: 250px;
    float: left; 
    height: 200px; 
    background-color: #0F0;
}
.right {
    width:100%;
    background-color: #F00; 
    height: 200px; 
   
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; display: table; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; min-width: 800px; max-width: 1100px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">Left div
            <br />(fixed to 250px)</div>
        <div class="right">Right div
            <br />(width fit to blue area left)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left` from the `right` element.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%; 
    min-width: 800px; 
    max-width: 1100px; 
    background-color: #06F; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 420px; 
    padding: 10px 0px;    
}
.left {
    width: 250px; 
    float: left; 
    height: 200px; 
    background-color: #0F0;
}
.right {
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #F00; 
    height: 200px; 
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            Left div<br />(fixed to 250px)
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            Right div<br />(width fit to blue area left)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```